# Django submit form and redirect to payment page then do form stuff

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/api) to have the customer pay when submitting the form. This integration redirects the customer to Stripe's page to do the payment. How can I make Django remember the input values from the Form after the payment is submitted on the redirected page? Can I create a custom URL that remembers the values?

Also their script requires a payment ID which I serve through a variable but this variable is first created once the form is submitted. I can't change a javascript variable dynamically once the page is rendered, right?

Javascript

```
<script>
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: "{{context}}",
    }).then(function (result) {
      // Diplay result.error.message to your customer
    });
    </script>
```

Python code to create the payment which is called **after** form submission

```
    stripeUID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    payment = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://mypage.com/succes",
  cancel_url="https://mypage.com/error",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  client_reference_id= stripeUID,
  line_items=[
    {
      "amount": 2000242,
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Blender rendering",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  ]
)   
    context = payment.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the payment ID, use AJAX. Submit the form with Javascript, and in the AJAX response serve the payment ID. then you can use it in the redirect. As for the redirect, you will need to create a model to store the form value against stripe session ID, so when your customer gets redirect back to your website, u can query the table with the session ID to get their original form values.

AJAX calls can be done by using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: This seems like the method that makes sense. Thanks very much for the input. I will research further now that i've got a direction to go.